# Gradle - Make existing android project a child of other project and run "gradlew tasks"

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Part  1.**

I have an existing Android project which is built with gradle.

`settings.gradle` looks like this:

```
include ':android', ':androidTest', ':androidTestApp'
```

`build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.4'
}

task customClean(dependsOn: [':android:clean', ':androidTest:clean', ':androidTestApp:clean']) {

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

What I need to do is a create a project that is a parent of this android project and runs this android project tasks. I add to `settings.gradle` of new root project only `include 'android-sdk:android'`which is all I need for now. And everything works fine, I can run tasks of android project like this `gradlew androidBuild`:

```
task androidBuild(dependsOn: 'android-sdk:android:assemble') << {
    group unitySdkGroupName
}
```

Problems arise when I run `gradlew tasks` on the new root projects. I get

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownTaskException: Task with path ':android:clean' not found in project ':android-sdk'.
```

I know I can fix this by removing colons like this, but I want to somehow make tasks command work without changing android project if possible.

```
    task customClean(dependsOn: ['android:clean', 'androidTest:clean', 'androidTestApp:clean']) {

}
```

**Part 2.**

When I add to `settings.gradle` of root project other nested projects

```
include 'android-sdk:androidTest'
include 'android-sdk:androidTestApp'
```

I get errors here in dependencies sections of child projects that are dependent on `android` module (this is `androidTest` module):

```
dependencies {
    compile project(path: ":android")
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

and getting this when I refresh projects (again seems like relative paths issue):

```
Error:(30, 0) Project with path ':android' could not be found in project ':android-sdk:androidTest'.
```

**So the question is** - can I make `gradlew tasks` command work properly without modifying the underlying android project and how can it be done the most elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately: no. Nested multiproject builds are not possible. I should add *yet*, but although intention to support them has been shown, there is absolutely no indication of when this feature can be expected.

See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/nested-multimodule-builds-with-a-flat-directory-layout/7509/13

I could not even find a feature request at https://discuss.gradle.org/c/bugs

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. I have worked around it by including a sub-sub project to he build `includeFlat 'android'
project(":android").projectDir = new File("android/android")`